# Как узнать содержимое json файла

Tags: java

Есть json файл. В нем либо объект (Map), либо массив (ArrayList).

Как заранее проверить файл на тип содержимого и использовать либо функцию чтения объекта, либо массива.

Comment: json... файл? Возможно, вы имели ввиду данные в формате json, которые сохранены в виде текстового файла? И что вам мешает сделать десереализацию?

Comment: >>либо массив (ArrayList)<< Поправка - ArrayList не массив. List - не массив. Collection - не массив. У вас есть объект либо объект. Повторяю вопрос, что мешает сделать десереализацию?

Comment: @test123 а есть пример десеаризации?

Comment: Как вариант: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14890129/jackson-deserialization-json-to-java-objects В jackson-е, как я понимаю, необходимо заранее знать десереализуемый тип. Тут вас может спасти только добавление сведений о классе/типе в json данные.

Answer (score 1):

Вообще конкретный вид JSON зависит от парсера или либы которая используется (например массив можно представить или как `List` или как `[]` или даже как `Vector`)

В случае `Map/List` обычно JSON выглядит так:

1) Для `List<String>` или `String[]` будет `["value1","value2"]`

2) Для `Map<String, String>`  будет `{"key1":"value1"}`

Comment: Я использую jackson. У меня два типа в файлах, как вы описали (Collection и Map). 

Как мне выяснить, что там лежит, а после уже парсить к тому типу, который там?

Comment: Если не хотите сильно думать, выбираете например парсинг `Map` и если словите `Exception` то парсите как `Collection` - дешево и сердито (очень сердито) :)

Comment: Я так и реализовал. По этому и ищу способ без Exception.